# why can not display HTML codes?

Tags: python

In test.txt, I have 2 lines of sentences.

```
The heart was made to be broken.
There is no surprise more magical than the surprise of being loved.
```

In codes:

```
import urllib2
file = open('/Users/name/Desktop/textfile.txt','r')
data = file.readlines()
file.close()
countline = 0
for line in data:
    countline = countline + 1
    line_replace = line.replace(" ", "+")
    line_url = 'http://sentistrength.wlv.ac.uk/results.php?text=' + line_replace + '&submit=Detect+Sentiment'
    requesturl = urllib2.Request(line_url)
    openurl = urllib2.urlopen(requesturl)
    readurl = openurl.read()
    print readurl
```

I am trying to print out HTML codes. If there is only 1 sentence in Textfile. Everything work fine but there is an error when there is 2 sentences in text file (I want to display html codes of both sentence.) Any possible way for solving this?

The error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode

Comment: `line_url` contains a `\n`, try printing out that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the Newline in the File is a problem here, try:

```
line_replace = line.replace(" ", "+").strip("\n")
```

Comment: Thank you. It work. (have to wait a few minutes before accepting the answer)